# Sharepoint 2010 PlaceHolder attribute # issue in multiple lines of text column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, html

I have a timer job with PlaceHolder ID and attritube is #. It checks a list and sends email every night. I created a EMAILTemplate list to send email. The body of the email is Multiple Lines of Text column. I am trying to send a link in body.

. When i save the item, it is converting to . So the user cannot open the link in the body of the email. I prefer to modify my EmailTemplate list rather than changing PlaceHolderAttritube.

FYI: It worked for a year but recently i modified a item in that list and saved it then it started behaving like this. Am using IE 9 right now.

Comment: Try converting it to a Rich Text field.

Comment: Converting it to Rich Text worked but it is diaplaying entire url. I want that url to be embedded to Title of that item. Is it possible?

Comment: You said you are using a timer Job, why can't you format it in Code? Also make sure you are storing the URL in Rich Text as `<a href="url">Title</a>`

Comment: Lets say url is www.google.com/ID=#ID# . and Title is Google . ID of that item is 1. I converted to rich text and typed <a href="url">Title</a> . I am receiving email exactly as <a href="www.google.com/ID=1">Google</a> .

Comment: How are you sending email.. Can you post the code? Is HTML enabled?

Comment: fieldXml = String.Format("<Field ID=\"{0}\" Name=\"{1}\" StaticName=\"{1}\" Type=\"Note\" NumLines=\"6\" RichText=\"TRUE\" DisplayName=\"{2}\" Required=\"FALSE\" ShowInDisplayForm=\"TRUE\" ShowInEditForm=\"TRUE\" ShowInNewForm=\"TRUE\" RichTextMode=\"FullHtml\"></Field>",
                        EmailFieldGuid[(int)EmailTemplates.EmailText],
                       EmailTemplates.EmailText.ToString(),

Comment: EmailText is the column name and it is HTML enabled as per RichTextMode=\"FullHtml\ above.